# When merging PDF files using itext the result pdf show 0 bytes in android studio

Tags: pdf

My code is here; I was selecting PDF files from a SD card or internal phone memory using the `showFileChooser()` method then from `onActivityResult()`, the files go to `mergePdfFiles(View view)` method, and from there the files go to `createPdf(String[] srcs)`.

Here is the complete code of my activity:
//Below is onCreate();

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mergedpdf);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locations);

    // public void fileSelected(File file ) {
    //      locations.add(file.toString());
    //      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //  }




    NewText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_items);



    btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);

    btnconvert = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);

    btnconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //   btTag=((Button)v).getTag().toString();

            try {
                createPdf( locations);
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(Mergedpdf.this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });





    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //   btTag=((Button)v).getTag().toString();
            showFileChooser();
            NewText.setText("Below Files are Selected");
        }
    });


}
```

//this is mergedfiles();

```
 public void mergePdfFiles(View view){
    Toast.makeText(Mergedpdf.this, "merge function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {String[] srcs= new String[locations.size()];
        for(int i = 0;i<locations.size();i++) {
            srcs[i] = locations.get(i);
        }

        //  String[] srcs = {txt1.getText().toString(), txt2.getText().toString()};
        createPdf(srcs);

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

//This method create merged pdf file

```
public void createPdf (String[] srcs) {
        try {
            // Create document object

            File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Merged-PDFFiles");
            if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
                docsFolder.mkdir();
                Log.i(TAG, "Created a new directory for PDF");
            }

            Date date = new Date();
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

            Document document = new Document();
            // pdfCopy = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),pdf+"Images.pdf");
            // Document document = new Document();
            //PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

            // Create pdf copy object to copy current document to the output mergedresult file
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(docsFolder + "/" + timeStamp +"combine.pdf"));
            Toast.makeText(Mergedpdf.this, "merged pdf saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Open the document
            document.open();
            PdfReader pr;

            int n;

            for (int i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
                // Create pdf reader object to read each input pdf file
                pr = new PdfReader(srcs[i].toString());
                // Get the number of pages of the pdf file
                n = pr.getNumberOfPages();

                for (int page = 1; page <= n; page++) {
                    // Import all pages from the file to PdfCopy
                    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(pr, page));
                }
            }

            document.close(); // close the document
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

//below is showfilechooser(); method

```
private void showFileChooser () {
    Log.e("AA", "bttag=" + btTag);
    String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(folderPath);
    intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "application/pdf");
    Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file");
    startActivityForResult(intentChooser,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
}
```

//below is onActivityResult(); method

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                locations.add(FilePath);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview,locations);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

//And my declared variables before oncreate().

```
   public com.itextpdf.text.Document Document;
public PdfCopy Copy;





public ByteArrayOutputStream ms;

TextView NewText;
private TextView txt1;
private Button bt1, bt2,bt3;
private Handler handler;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ImageView btn, btnconvert, btn3;
private static final String TAG = "PdfCreator";

private final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE=10;

private String btTag = "";
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what problem you're running into. Could you elaborate?

Comment: sir i pick multiple pdf file from phone internal memory using Array adapter string and trying to merged these file using above method .the resulting merged file is created but show 0byte and cant open in any pdf viewer ..

Comment: you may want to incorporate that problem into your question.

Comment: sir i update my question with my full code ....please check

Comment: Have you found any stack traces from `e.printStackTrace()` in `createPdf`? Have you tried adding debug output to `createPdf` to check the actual program flow?